# Drop down menu UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to implement a UI like as shown in the below image. When the button (shown from the arrow) is clicked then the drop down menu should come.
Is it possible to do this in android?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Suggestions for what? You want us to do your job?

Comment: @Shishdem i don't want u to do my job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use popup window for this type of options:

```
llBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                showPopupMenu();
            }
        });
```

and the showPopupMenu() method is:

```
public void showPopupMenu() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_file_lay,
                this.container, false);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, popupwidth,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popUpwindowinIt(popupView);

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.places), 0, 0);

    }
```

here in above code R.id.places is the hidden layout in layout file where we want to show the menu, like below the menu button;

and here is the add_file_lay named view to show as popup menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#262127" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downarrow_afile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gallerylay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/gallerybtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/gal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/gallerytxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/gallerybtn"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Gallery"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/photolay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/photobtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/cam" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phototxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/photobtn"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Take Photo"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/videolay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/videobtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/video" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/videotxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/videobtn"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Video"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/audiolay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/audiobtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ausio" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/audiotxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/audiobtn"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Audio"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/locationlay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/locationbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/location" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/locationtxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/locationbtn"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Location"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutAddContact"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/contactbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/contact" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_below="@id/contactbtn"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Contact"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm getting errors for container, popupWindow and places. What should I do? I'm trying this on a activity.

Comment: container is just a ViewGroup container; popupWindow is PopupWindow popupWindow; and places as i told you the place where you want to show the popup as <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/places"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

First make that dropdown menu invisible
 Add onclick event to button and when it got clicked make that dropdown menu visible.That's what i can suggest since i can't see your uploaded image

Comment: How can I do the drop down? Is it a fragment? I'm bit confused there